# Back button not working on Ipad's default browser(Safari)

Tags: javascript

Let me tell you the scenario of my problem. In my application i am having 100 item to show to user but for the first time only 15 item will be showed as user will scroll down spinning icon will blink for a moment and more item will be showed to him/her(15,30,45 till the last item). when user clicks on any item,details of that item will be showed. on the details page there is one back button which will take user to items page. so on click of back button again on scrolling more items will get showed. Please have a look on the code for scrolling and back button.

Now this code is working fine for all the browsers only it is not working on Ipad's default browser(Safari).

Even it is working on desktop safari version with same user-agent.

Scroll logic :

```
$(window).scroll( function() 
{
 reloadq() //function to display more items
}
```

Back button coding :

```
href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="back-btn">Back
```

Comment: This looks an awful lot like javascript.. not java.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll work (I have no iPad to test on), but you could try using `href="javascript:window.history.back()"` instead.